How can I use MockK to return a particular value from a constructor?
I'm writing some Kotlin tests, and I want to mock the return value of a particular method of an object that's constructed.
Right now I have
every{
   anyConstructed<FooMaker>.execute(fooId)
} returns testFoo

This compiles, but when run fails with the exception:
io.mockk.MockKException: to use anyConstructed<T>() or constructedWith<T>(...) first build mockkConstructor<T>() and 'use' it

This example from the documentation works just fine:
every { anyConstructed<MockCls>().add(1, 2) } returns 4

What does this error mean? How do I build mockkConstructor<Foo> and 'use' it?

In general, you need to call mockkConstructor before the every block:
mockkConstructor(Foo::class)
every {
    anyConstructed<Foo>().execute(fooId)
} returns testFoo

This creates a mock constructor for Foo that the every block can use.
See the documentation here.

I think the cryptic "'use' it" part of that misleading error message means that you can use a variant of mockkConstructor that takes a lambda (block)as its final parameter. It executes the block and then unmocks the constructor. So: mockkConstructor(Foo::class) { every { ... } ...; test of your test here... } If you don't do that, you should manually call unmockkConstructor at the end of your test.

@k314159: If you write that up as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it.
